# Flutter: Textfield in overlay triggering rebuilds

Tags: dart, flutter, overlay, textfield

I can't seem to figure out why the code below prints `built` three times (calls `State.build`) after you hit the button to show the `Overlay` and focus the `Textfield`.

Now, I know that a `MaterialApp` inside another `MaterialApp` is not a good idea and that's the second part of the problem: Why won't the `Keyboard` (testing on a physical device with `Android 8.1.0`) appear when I remove the `MaterialApp` wrapped around the `Scaffold` and try to focus the `Textfield`? There is a `MaterialApp` at the root whose `Overlay` `Overlay.of(context)` should find.

```
import "package:flutter/material.dart";
import "package:flutter/services.dart";

void main() {
  SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays([]);
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: MyOtherApp()
      )
    )
  );
}

class MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  TextEditingController controller = TextEditingController();

  @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      controller.text = "placeholder";

      return MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
          body: (){
            print("built");
            return TextField(
              controller: controller,
            );
          }()
        )
      );
    }
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
    State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
      return MyAppState();
    }
}

class MyOtherApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return Center(
        child: FlatButton(
          child: Text(
            "show overlay",
          ),
          onPressed: () {
            Overlay.of(context).insert(
              OverlayEntry(
                builder: (context) {
                  return MyApp();
                }
              )
            );
          }
        )
      );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I put SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays([]); under the build instead in the main.